# Use CSS and z-index to create a page overlay, then place one element on top of the overlay

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

How can I place an overlay over my page, while selecting specific elements to be placed on-top of the overlay?

For example, place a dark overlay over your entire page and let a button be on top of it.  This will highlight the button.   You can see a demo of this effect used in [intro.js](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)

**What I've tried:**

I tried it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ne83oa4/1/), but it didn't work.

Basically I make an overlay div by doing `position: fixed; z-index: 100;`, and let one element shine through it by giving it `position: relative; z-index: 101;`. But for some reason, my inner div still shows up below the overlay instead of ontop, despite having a higher z-index than the overlay.

How can I position these elements so `inner` appears ontop of `overlay`?

**How introJS seems to work... against the z-index spec**

IntroJS has an overlay with z-index: 99998, then the highlighted element has classes applied to it that give it `position: relative; z-index: 99999;`. We wouldn't think this would work, given how stacking works... but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His original fiddle works.  It was a coloring issue.  When showing an overlay with different colors, make sure the two colors you use aren't visually similar so that this mistake isn't made again.

Ultimately, `position: relative` *does* create a new stacking context.  No point in trying to save face.

## I'll leave the following in memorium to my hubris thinking I knew something that intro.js didn't

Woo boy.  This one's fun.

So you've fallen into the old **[stacking context problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_context_example_3)**.

In short, what you're trying to do, you can't do.

**[Fiddle incoming!](http://jsfiddle.net/4ne83oa4/4/)**

In this fiddle:

**We change some CSS**

```
.container {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    height: 30px;
}
```

**What this does**

Basically, it pops your stack to be an equal with your `.overlay` element.

The `position: relative` on the `.container` element ensures that when we pop a `position:absolute` on the `.inner` element that it stays where it should, but if you were to remove it, the `.inner` element will still pop above your overlay. Fascinating, right?  I'll explain why in an edit after I write it up, but I want to get this out to you before someone snipes my rightful answer.

The `width:100%` keeps the element displaying as if it were rendered normally within flow.

In order to have it displace other elements within flow, you'll need to take additional measures, and I'll need to see some contextual examples for that.

That should solve it for you, though.

Comment: The tricky part is I'm trying to highlight a button (and other elements) on a real webapp, which means they are deeply nested in other HTML parts of the page

Comment: @DonnyP - Edited up accordingly, more explanations forthcoming.

Comment: Thanks for the effort Josh - really appreciate it. The jsfiddle with your method doesn't seem to work though

Comment: Sure it does, at least in Chrome (where I'm currently working).  Here's an example with the opacity of your top box set to 1: http://jsfiddle.net/4ne83oa4/5/

Comment: Wait a second, in your original question, what browser are you using? - http://jsfiddle.net/4ne83oa4/7/

That's the original fiddle with some color and formatting changes to make the `.inner` element less ambiguously colored.

Comment: Ahhh, it does work! My bad, I didn't realize that the blue was behind the green now, not overlaying it. I'm using Chrome :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64973/discussion-between-josh-burgess-and-donny-p).